# SiteFinity URL Rewriting Regular Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, sitefinity

I'm struggling with a URL Rewriting rule for SiteFinity. I am trying to make sure that you can only access the homepage via `/` and not `/default.aspx`.

I tried the following rule:

```
<rule mode="PermanentRedirect">
    <url>/default.aspx</url>
    <rewrite>/</rewrite>
</rule>
```

Which actually works perfectly on the homepage - however it also catches `/sitefinity/default.aspx` and redirects off the homepage - not very helpful for content editors!

I essentially need a rule that will match when there is nothing prior to the string `/default.aspx`.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<url>^/default\.aspx</url>
```

`^` in most regular expression flavors means "start of the string", so it wouldn't match if the pattern is found in the middle. In addition, since `<url>` should be a regular expression, remember to escape the dot - a dot means "anything <sub><sup>(except newlines)</sup></sub>", so your pattern matches also `/defaultXaspx`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure of how things are looking from your machine's perspective.

I'm thinking that you would want to do a 'search and replace'  like this.

```
strreplace "/default.aspx" with "/"
```

and then don't do anything with the other cases.